# Django set ManytoManyField to default user model

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I need to set a `manytomany` relation to default django user table.Is there any way to implement it rather than using `AbstractUser` method of django 
(extending User Model)?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Django's [**`get_user_model()`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model), as is specified in the documentation:

> Instead of referring to `User` directly, you **should reference the user model using `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`**. This method will return the **currently active user model** – the custom user model if one is specified, or `User` otherwise.

Even if you are using Django's default user model, it is better to use `get_user_model`, since if you later change your mind, you can alter the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL), and the reference to the user model will be updated.

For example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())
```

Using `AbstractUser` will *not* work, since this is an abstract model, and it will not refer to the user model you use.

Furthermore you do *not* have to subclass `AbstractUser` yourself if you want to use Django's builtin `User` model. You subclass `AbstractUser` if you wish to define a user model yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend the default Django User table to create a many to many relationship with it.

Add the many to many relation to the model you're creating, and behind the scenes Django will create a third table that stores the relationship using a ForeignKey to each object.